# solve and store two unknown variable in an equation in for loop matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate the heat flow equation eqns_N = [H*AN*L*(i-Tw1) == k*AN*(Tw1-Tw2), k*AN*(Tw1-Tw2) == H1*AN*L*(Tw2-T2)]; i is the input values from excel and I want to store each variable of Tw1 and Tw2 in an array. Currently I'm getting only one value in 1X1 sym format
Below is the code:-

```
for j = 2:numel(Tsol_N)
    i=Tsol_N(j);
    eqns_N = [H*AN*L*(i-Tw1) == k*AN*(Tw1-Tw2), k*AN*(Tw1-Tw2) == H1*AN*L*(Tw2-T2)];
    S_N= solve(eqns_N, [Tw1 Tw2],'Real',true);
    res = subs(S_N,{Tw1,Tw2});
    %Tw1(i).Tw1 = double(S_N.Tw1);
    %Tw2(i).Tw2 = double(S_N.Tw2);
    overall_cooling_load = H*AN*(S_N.Tw2 - T2);
    rounded_overall_cooling_load = double(overall_cooling_load);
    overall_cooling_load1 = [overall_cooling_load ; Tsol_N];
    rounded_overall_cooling_load2= [rounded_overall_cooling_load ; Tsol_N];

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to use `j` as an index in the loop.

```
for j = 2:numel(Tsol_N)
   ...
   eqns_N(j-1) = ...
   S_N(j-1) = ...
   res(j-1) = subs(S_N(j-1), {Tw1, Tw2});
```

and so on. That way you'll have the first result store in `res(1)`, the second in `res(2)`.

Remember to pre-allocate memory for the matrices in order to avoid growing matrices.

If the outputs are not scalars then I suggest you use cells:

```
for j = 2:numel(Tsol_N)
   ...
   eqns_N{j-1} = ...
   S_N{j-1} = ...
   res{j-1} = subs(S_N{j-1}, {Tw1, Tw2});
```

Comment: Did you try the cell version with curly brackets in the bottom?

Comment: Yeah, Trying it now. That's y i deleted it.

Comment: Hi.. Yeah code is executing and the data is being stores in res in struct format spreading over in single rows, but i want Tw1 and Tw2 in one column separately in an array form. I tried this code : for j = 2:numel(Tsol_N)
    i=Tsol_N(j);
    eqns_N = [H*AN*L*(i-Tw1) == k*AN*(Tw1-Tw2), k*AN*(Tw1-Tw2) == H1*AN*L*(Tw2-T2)];
    S_N= solve(eqns_N, [Tw1 Tw2],'Real',true);
    temp = struct2cell(S_N);
    double(horzcat(temp{:}'))  but unable to store (horzcat(temp{:}'))  in an array

Comment: This appears to be a new question that warrants a new post. You can skip most of the code you have in this post. Simply show the output you have now, and show how you want it (and what you have attempted). You can reference this post for context. You may alternatively update this post with the additional information, but I don't think I can help you any further since I don't have MATLAB at hand. You'll likely get more attention if you post a new one, and in my opinion, they will not be duplicates.

Comment: Thank you Stewie, I able to get the values now but i'm getting 1041X1 matrix instead of 1042X1 matrix. Is this because I used j-1 method in for loop? Is there any way to overcome from it

Comment: Yes. Either loop from 1 and just use `j` instead of `j-1` or loop to numel()+1, assuming you don't get "index exceed matrix dimensions". I don't know which will be best for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I got the solution now I just removed -1.